# how to extend the valued field embedding?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, field-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

let $(K,V)$ and $(L,W)$ be two algebraically closed valued fields,and $E$ be a sub-field of $K$ . for a valued field embedding $f$ from $E$ to $L$, how should I extend it to a valued field embedding from algebraically closure of $E$ to $L$?

Comment: It would help to know what you know already - in general, you should add as much context as you can to your question. For example, do you know how to extend a valuation on a field $E$ to *some* valuation on its algebraic closure $\overline{E}$? Is there a unique way to do that, or multiple ways? If there are multiple ways, how are they related? Can you extend $f\colon E\to L$ to an embedding *of fields* $\overline{E}\to L$? These are all natural questions to ask, and their answers are components of the answer to your question.

Comment: no so sorry ....I don't know... where can I read about it? maybe it is possible to extend the valuation on algebraic closure by taking the minimal polynomial of each element in the closure.... I'm not sure....

Answer (score 0):

This is a crucial step in the proof of quantifier elimination for ACVF, the theory of algebraically closed valued fields. So you can find proofs or at least references in many sources which prove this theorem.

For example: In these [notes by Freitag](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~freitag/valuations.pdf), the statement you want is exactly Lemma 2.5. Freitag gives a short proof, but refers to other references for the proof of a crucial algebraic component of the proof (Theorem 2.6).

In these [notes by van den Dries](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~freitag/valfields.pdf), the statement you want is Corollary 3.14 (but phrased in the language of valuation rings, rather than valuations - see p.25 for the correspondence between valuation rings and valuations). All the algebraic details are in the other results stated on p. 28, whose proofs are given on p. 29 and p. 30.